# Another number sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

> 2, 3, 5, 11, 31, 127, 709, 5381, ?

What are the next three numbers in the sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is:

> 52711- as seen from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+11%2C+31%2C+127%2C+709%2C+5381&language=english&go=Search)

Explanation:

> 1st prime=2.
> 2nd prime=3
>  3rd prime=5
>  5th prime=11
>  11th prime=31
>  31st prime=127
>  127th prime=709
>  709th prime=5381
>  5381st prime=52711

Comment: Guess I should have checked OEIS. Congrats :\